# Get a list of all possible paths with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I wonder if there's some way with [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) to get a list of all possible paths with the routes configuration?

For example, from this:

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="/">
        <DefaultRoute .../>
        <Route name="about" .../>
        <Route name="blog" .../>
    </Route>
);
```

I'd like:

`["/", "/about", "/blog"]`

Comment: What's the use case for this? Also, it might be possible with `createRouter.getChildContext().routeHandlers`;

Comment: @limelights for a static web deployment, server-side rendering every possible page and uploading to a S3-like service.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me, with v0.13:

```
var router = Router.create(routes);

var routePaths = [];
for (var i in router.namedRoutes) {
    routePaths.push(router.namedRoutes[i].path);
}

//routePaths = ['/', '/about', '/blog']
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. **The simplest:** See your routes as an array by checking your props (`this.props.routes`). However, this includes a lot of extra data you aren't necessarily looking for.
2. **More robust:** Use a community-built tool like [react-router-query](https://github.com/elliottsj/react-router-query), [react-router-to-array](https://github.com/alansouzati/react-router-to-array), or [react-router-sitemap](https://github.com/kuflash/react-router-sitemap). All have fairly robust read-me's you can dig into.

Someone asked a similar question [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800296/react-router-get-all-routes-as-array) with more detailed responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function for this purpose:

```js
    /**
     * Get list of paths
     * @param routes {JSX.Element}
     */
    const getRoutes = (routes) =>
    {
        const paths = new Set();
        /**
         * Walk in list of routes tree
         * @param element {JSX.Element}
         */
        const walkTree = (element) =>
        {
            if (element.props.children && element.props.children.length > 0)
            {
                element.props.children.forEach((elem) => walkTree(elem));
            }
            else if (element.props.path && typeof element.props.path === 'string')
            {
                paths.add(element.props.path);
            }
        }
        walkTree(routes);
        return paths;
    };
```

A complete react sample (Tested with react 6):

```js
import './App.scss';

import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './pages/login.page';
import Pricing from './pages/pricing.page';
import Register from './pages/register.page';
import Home from './pages/home.page';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard.page';
import Authenticator from './components/Authenticator.component';
import Profile from './pages/Profile.page';

const App = () => {
    const routes = (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login />} />
            <Route exact path='/register' element={<Register />} />
            <Route exact path='/pricing' element={<Pricing />} />
            <Route path='/' element={<Authenticator />}/>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route exact path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/*' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
    );
    
    /**
     * Get list of paths
     * @param routes {JSX.Element}
     */
    const getRoutes = (routes) =>
    {
        const paths = new Set();
        /**
         * Walk in list of routes tree
         * @param element {JSX.Element}
         */
        const walkTree = (element) =>
        {
            if (element.props.children && element.props.children.length > 0)
            {
                element.props.children.forEach((elem) => walkTree(elem));
            }
            else if (element.props.path && typeof element.props.path === 'string')
            {
                paths.add(element.props.path);
            }
        }
        walkTree(routes);
        return paths;
    };
    
    console.log(getRoutes(routes));
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <main id='main' className="main">
                { routes }
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This works but does not give the correct routes. It gave me `'books', 'bookhistory/:id', 'new', ':id', '/users'` instead it shud have given, `'/books', '/bookhistory/:id', '/books/new', '/books/:id', '/users'` i.e., it does not take into account the path of the parent element. It should concatenate that path to give proper output