# React Router: get all routes as array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there an existing library that will reduce my route instance to an array of paths?

**Example**:

```
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="author" component={Author}>
        <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="users" component={Users} />
    </Route>
```

**Output**

```
['/', '/author', '/author/about', '/users']
```

I could write a reduce function that will have few lines of code and solve that, but I was wondering if there is an existing library that will do that for me and take care of the different ways of representating routes using react router.

Comment: what is the use case for this?

Comment: I want to use a plugin for webpack for static site generation. In short, I want to publish my app in github.io and I'm using react router. See this project: https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin. They expect an array of routes as their entry.

Comment: here is one which generates sitemap [react-router-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap), but I think  you are better off with a simple reduce (like you said), until you have more complex routes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of all possible paths with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656792/get-a-list-of-all-possible-paths-with-react-router)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I did not find anything, I ended up creating a library for that...

https://github.com/alansouzati/react-router-to-array

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import reactRouterToArray from 'react-router-to-array';
// or var reactRouterToArray = require('react-router-to-array');

console.log(reactRouterToArray(
  <Route path="/" component={FakeComponent}>
    {/* just to test comments */}
    <IndexRoute component={FakeComponent} />
    <Route path="about" component={FakeComponent}>
      <Route path="home" component={FakeComponent} />
      <Route path="/home/:userId" component={FakeComponent} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="users" component={FakeComponent} />
    <Route path="*" component={FakeComponent} />
  </Route>)
); //outputs: ['/', '/about', '/about/home', '/users']
```

Comment: Your example inlines the routes. But in a real world app my routes are inside a switch inside a class component (in fact: `<React.Fragment> -> <ScrollToTop> -> <Switch>`. How would I get it from there?

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand why you need a library. Your `Routes` should be available as an `Array` in the props.

An example:

[image]

Comment: From you printscreen I can see you are using plain routes (as a JSON object). Another possible way to represent a route is to use JSX, which has a different structure itself, for example: childRoutes is represented as props.children. Another limitation is that I need a single level array of strings  and this structure is still nested.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a library specifically for this purpose: https://github.com/elliottsj/react-router-query

It can handle asynchronous routes (i.e. `getChildRoutes` / `getIndexRoute`), and provides not just an array of paths, but an array of "FlatRoute" objects which contain the path (`fullPath`), plus all of the original properties of each route, and an array of "parent" routes:

```js
import { query } from 'react-router-query';

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="author" component={Author}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="users" component={Users} />
  </Route>
);

query('/', routes, (error, result) => {
  expect(result).toEqual([
    {
      fullPath: '/author/about'
      component: About,
      parents: [
        { path: '/', component: App },
        { path: 'author', component: Author },
      ],
    },
    {
      fullPath: '/users'
      component: Users,
      parents: [
        { path: '/', component: App },
      ],
    },
  ]);
});
```

Note that only "leaf" routes are included in the result: there is no "FlatRoute" object for `fullPath: '/'` nor `fullPath: '/author'`. This is to prevent including routes that are only used as a layout for child routes, e.g.

```js
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="posts" component={PostLayout}>
    <Route path="1" component={Post1} />
    <Route path="2" component={Post2} />
    <Route path="3" component={Post3} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

If you want a FlatRoute for `/posts`, simply include an `IndexRoute`:

```js
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="posts">
    <IndexRoute component={Posts} />
    <Route path="1" component={Post1} />
    <Route path="2" component={Post2} />
    <Route path="3" component={Post3} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you update the library to use react >= 17?

Answer (score 0):

You can take Router and its nested components in variable
and render it necessary place, and you can use that variable to get list of possible routes, I did it for some level only because it was matching my case, so didn't bothered doing it, but we can apply recursion to fetch all.

Below is an example
I took allRoutes = `<Router> .......... </Router>`

```
let allData = []
  allRoutes && allRoutes?.props?.children.forEach((element,index) => {
    element && element['forEach'] && element?.forEach((eleRoute)=>{
      allData.push(eleRoute.props.path)
    })

    if(element && typeof(element) == 'object' && element['props'] && element.props['path']){
      allData.push(element.props['path'])
    }
    element && element?.props?.children && Array.isArray(element?.props?.children) && element?.props?.children.forEach((eachelement, eachIndex)=>{
        
        if(eachelement?.props?.path){
          console.log("DONE")
          allData.push(eachelement?.props?.path);
        }
      
  });
```