# React router V6 check or test if a pathname does exist in routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i wanna check if a route exist in my routes, how can i do that
i tried using matchPath but it just matches a pattern to some path, i wanna test if a route exist, is there a way to do it ?

```
const handleNotifClick = (link, id) => {
        setIsFetchingNotifs(true);
        // check if "link"(pathname) exist in routes. what should i remplace "exist" with ??
        if(exist) navigate(link);
        else navigate('/access-denied');
        if (acl?.notification?.put_notification_as_seen) axiosPut(`notification/mark-as-seen/${id}`);
};
```

link is just a string that comes from the api, something like '/products' i wanna check if that link exist in my routes, so i can navigate to it, else i wanna navigate to access-denied

exist is just a placeholder, its the thing that im looking for

Comment: Could you share code and be more specific with the use case? `matchPath` should be able to handle most use cases.

Comment: i added some code, i dont know exactly how can i use matchPath

Comment: @MoncifJbara, Isn't it that ```if(exist)``` needs **to** be ```if(link)``` ?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan no, link is just a string that comes from the api, something like '/products' i wanna check if that link exist in my routes, so i can navigate to it, else i wanna navigate to access-denied

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router: get all routes as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800296/react-router-get-all-routes-as-array)

Comment: @MoncifJbara, Check this code for reference of implementation,  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-zmtpxs . Take keen look on ```useLocation``` .

Comment: @ManirajMurugan srry but i dont wanna compare link with current pathname, i need to see if it exists in all routes

Comment: @MoncifJbara, Could you explain how the route exactly will look like?

Comment: What if you just navigated to the `link` target.... and render the "access-denied" route as the general fallback for any unmatched paths? Between the router, `Routes` and `Route`s components, RRD already knows what routes/paths it can link to and render. If this isn't what you want and you *absolutely* need do this check first then I suggest following one of the solutions from @Ergis's comment, or define locally a `routes` config that is passed to [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes) that you can crawl yourself for defined paths.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using plain js.

Basically you can use `window.location` to find what path is current displayed:

```
const currentURL = window.location.href // returns the absolute URL of a page

const pathName = window.location.pathname //returns the current url minus the domain name
```

Then I did it to not display a component based on the route with the `pathname`:

**url**: **http://localhost:3000/create**

```
         . . .
              {
                pathName === "/create" ? (
                 ""
                ) : (
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link
                  className={`nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4 ${OtherClassName}`}
                  as={Link}
                  to="/create"
                >
                  Create
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
         ...
```